# Statistics hypothesis testing problem - vague question

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am working on revising my statistics knowledge and I came upon an exercise which I don't know how to do.

I have been given two sets of data *samples*:

```
Weights:
25  24  12  8   15  2   23  9   26  9
5   26  19  29  28  2   27  7   1   20
10  6   9   1   1   28  27  30
```

```
Heights:
150 196 155 165 173 158 191 159 170 195
157 175 153 179 186 191 189 158 161 155
201 186 154 200 184 176 164 195
```

The exercise says:

Test the hypothesis: The weights of the suitcases depend on the height of the passenger. Note that α=0.05.

Now, I'm having problems figuring this out. I need to set the $H_0$ and $H_1$ hypotheses, but the exercises I was working on were dealing with numerical values (e.g. Test the hypothesis that the average life of a battery will be greater than 70 years). We always used to test if $μ < μ_0, μ>μ_0, μ≠μ_0$ (in the above-mentioned example, 70 would be $μ_0$. I'd then calculate the $t$ value via the formula, and $t_0$ I'd find from the table (that's why I'm given the alpha value).

I know that the formula for the $t$ value is $$t=\frac{x̄ - μ_0}{ \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}   }$$

And after that
where v=n-1

However the question I have been given here is pretty vague. I tried everything, from putting a random value as $μ_0$ (one from the set of data) but everything I do does not work. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You could estimate the coefficient $a$ in $w = ah+b$, where w is the weight and h the height, and test the hypothesis $a\neq0$ vs $a=0$

Comment: @NicoDeTullio : but in this way you test only a linear dependence...the question is different. I think it can be easily solved with a non- parametric test, i.e. $\chi^2$ test

Comment: @tommik Could you please provide an answer as to how?

Answer (score 1):

I put your data into R and made a scatterplot, which
shows no obvious correlation, linear or otherwise.

```
w=c(25, 24, 12, 8, 15, 2, 23, 9, 26, 9, 5, 26, 19, 29, 
    28, 2, 27, 7, 1, 20, 10, 6, 9, 1, 1, 28, 27, 30) 
h=c(150, 196, 155, 165, 173, 158, 191, 159, 170, 195,
    157, 175, 153, 179, 186, 191, 189, 158, 161, 155,
    201, 186, 154, 200, 184, 176, 164, 195)
plot(h,w)
```

[image]

A test whether the (Pearson) correlation is significantly different from $0$ does not reject the null hypothesis
that data are not correlated.

```
cor.test(h,w)

        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  h and w
t = 0.47052, df = 26, p-value = 0.6419
alternative hypothesis: 
   true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2911722  0.4495522
sample estimates:
       cor 
0.09188625
```

That may not be the end of the story. However, not
knowing what your text means by 'the hypothesis' I don't know where to go from here that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let X and Y be two rv's with joint law $F_{XY}(x,y)$ and let $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$ their marginal laws.

Let's suppose to have the following System of Hypothesis to verify:

$$ \begin{cases} \mathcal{H}_0: F_{XY}(x,y)=F_X(x)\cdot F_Y(y),  & \text{for every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$} \\ \mathcal{H}_1: F_{XY}(x,y) \ne F_X(x)\cdot F_Y(y),  & \text{for some$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$} \end{cases}$$

We want to verify this hypothesis system using the $\chi^2$ test so, first

Let's re-organize the data in a table, for example like this

[image]

- The first table is the one of the data
- The second table is the one supposing independence
- The third table is the test: $\sum\frac{(O-E)^2}{ E}$

The pvalue is determined with the calculator (or tables) thus the test $\sim\chi_{(1)}^2$ and results more than 74%.

To reject the hypothesis of independence this pvalue must be less than $\alpha$

Concluding: we have not enough evidence as to reject the hypothesis of independence.

There are a lot of other Non parametric test to check independence

- Kendall's $\tau$ Test
- Spearman's $\rho$  Test
- Gini's G Test

You can find all the detail on specific textbooks

Comment: How are you testing a nonlinear dependence here?

Comment: @NicoDeTullio : I edited my answer with the specification of the hypothesis system to be verified. You can find all the details on specific textbooks but as you surely know, this is a non parametric test, which works without specifying the law of the rv's

Comment: My point is that by binning the data that way you are still not going to test a nonlinear dependence.